# Is it Possible to scan for a client I.P. with a specific M.A.C. Address in Android?

Tags: android, mac-address

Currently, I am making an app which will scan the router and search for a client IP having the given MAC Address.

Is there any way with which I can determine the list of connected clients on the network with their MAC Addresses respectively?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol

Comment: Is there any process with which i can implement this in android?